# jQuery Mobile - Trouble with calculations and onClick

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am a beginner on jQuery mobile and I'm trying to make a simple function that helps people to make an energy calculation by using one slider for area, radiobutton groups for glastype today and a material called moniflex that will be used instead of the glas and will result in a energy saving.

The issues I have is:
- The onclick event does not work on safari mac/iPhone.
- I get different values, but with the same selections made.

The code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">


    function displayVals() {

      var area = $("#slider1").val();
      var glas = $("input[name='Ftyp']:checked").val();
      var moniflex = $("input[name='Mflex']:checked").val();
      var summary = parseFloat(area * (glas - moniflex) * 107.28);
      $("#Resultat").html(parseInt(summary) + " kWh");

    }

   </script> 

    <div data-role="page" class="gridContainer clearfix">
    <div id="LayoutDiv1">
    <div data-role="header" id="Header"><img src="img/top.jpg"></div>
    <div data-role="content" id="Content">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <div id="Resultat" class="Sum">0 kWh</div>
    <div id="Yta">
    <label for="slider">Value:</label>
    <input type="range" name="slider1" id="slider1" value="0" min="0" max="1000" step="1" onChange="displayVals();" data-highlight="true" />

      </div>
      <div id="Glas">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" onClick="displayVals();" >
            <legend>Option</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="Ftyp" id="Ftyp_0" value="5.5" />
            <label for="Ftyp_0">Enkelglas</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Ftyp" id="Ftyp_1" value="3" />
            <label for="Ftyp_1">Dubbelglas</label>
          </fieldset>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div id="Material">
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" onClick="displayVals();" >
            <legend>MONIFLEX</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="Mflex" id="Mflex_0" value="3" />
            <label for="Mflex_0">10mm</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Mflex" id="Mflex_1" value="1.9" />
            <label for="Mflex_1">20mm</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Mflex" id="Mflex_2" value="1.4" />
            <label for="Mflex_2">30mm</label>
          </fieldset>
          </div>

    </div>  
      </div>




    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What value did you received on Safari/iOS?

Answer (score 1):

I found your problem. Click on a controlgroup is not enough because you will try to find a radio value before radiobox is actually selected. You will need to create a slight timeout.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/yRbUT/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#test-page', function(){       
    $(document).on('click', '[data-role="controlgroup"]', function(){       
        setTimeout(function () { displayVals(); }, 100);
    });
    $( "#slider1" ).on('slidestop', function(event, ui) {
      displayVals();
    });    
});

function displayVals() {
    var area = $("#slider1").val();
    var glas = $("input[name='Ftyp']:checked").val();
    var moniflex = $("input[name='Mflex']:checked").val();
    var summary = parseFloat(area * (glas - moniflex) * 107.28);
    $("#Resultat").html(parseInt(summary) + " kWh");
    alert(area + ' - ' + glas + ' - ' +  moniflex);    
}
```

Also if possible do not use onclick with jQuery Mobile. Instead bind events by yourself, like in my example.

Comment: I would use vclick rather than click in jQuery Mobile. click is too slow, and may not fire in some cases on mobile devices.

Comment: Hi, thanks alot for the answer! This works much better, but i still dont get the information to update on Safari mobile, see link http://www.isolight.se/mobile/index.html

Comment: I updated the script with touchstart and click, but now i have to click the radiobutton twice to get a updated value. '$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#test-page', function(){       
    $(document).on('touchstart click', '[data-role="controlgroup"]', function(){       
        setTimeout(function () { displayVals(); }, 100);
    });
    $( "#slider1" ).on('slidestop', function(event, ui) {
      displayVals();
    });    
});'